# Is there is a possible way to fill color between css double border?

Tags: html, css, border

Hello Guys I Would Like to Fill a Different Color in My `css` Double Border.I Know that it is Possible by Using Two Borders.

```css
#parent{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content : center;
  background-color:red;
}
#child{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

But here I would like to have a solution with a single Border Property(Single `<div>` or any other Element).So I Used css `double`  Property.Is there is any Possible way to fill color on this double_border?

```css
#element{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:10px double #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

> **Please Note** :- Somebody Tagged That This is Possible Duplicate of
>   Another.Just Please Read Both of the Question before You Tagg. This
>   question is different,on that question he is asking for color the the
>   two borders with different color.but here I would like to keep two
>   borders with same color,I just wanna to fill some color between
>   them.hope you will understand the problem.

Comment: @Andrew sorry this question is different.on that question he is asking for color the the two borders with different color.but here I would like to keep two borders with same color,I just wanna to fill some color between them.hope you will understand the problem.

Comment: maybe you should look into the css `border-image` property. There are tools out there that can help you with this like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator). I have used this to make a rainbow border, so a double color border should be do-able

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use multiple box-shadows:

```css
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #000, 0 0 0 6px #f00, 0 0 0 9px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

Comment: wow good logic...

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting the border to be any thickness other than what's in your example. Doesn't seem to scale very well.

Comment: @j08691 Because the shadow is not part within the div, this can be fixed with margin. Give the element the margin of the widest shadow and it will work

Answer (score 2):

You can by using the `border`, `box-shadow`, and `outline` properties.

```css
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black; /* inner border */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 15px black; /* outer 'border' */
  outline: 12px solid green; /* fill */
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

Comment: thanks you understand the actual problem and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo-element to accomplish this:

https://jsfiddle.net/82zn96Lu/

```css
#doubleBorder {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 6px solid red;
}

#doubleBorder:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  border: 6px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="doubleBorder">
  a double border
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your support